# How to move part of text to another line in PHP

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

Here is the code I am using:

```php
// Display the product variation price inside the variations dropdown. add_filter( 'woocommerce_variation_option_name', 'display_price_in_variation_option_name' );
function display_price_in_variation_option_name( $term ) {
    global $wpdb, $product;

    if ( empty( $term ) ) {
        return $term;
    }

    if ( empty( $product->id ) ) {
        return $term;
    }

    $result    = $wpdb->get_col( "SELECT slug FROM {$wpdb->prefix}terms WHERE name = '$term'" );
    $term_slug = ( ! empty( $result ) ) ? $result[0] : $term;

    $query = "
        SELECT postmeta.post_id AS product_id
        FROM {$wpdb->prefix}postmeta AS postmeta
        LEFT JOIN {$wpdb->prefix}posts AS products ON ( products.ID = postmeta.post_id )
        WHERE postmeta.meta_key LIKE 'attribute_%'
        AND postmeta.meta_value = '$term_slug'
        AND products.post_parent = $product->id";

    $variation_id = $wpdb->get_col( $query );
    $parent       = wp_get_post_parent_id( $variation_id[0] );

    if ( $parent > 0 ) {
        $_product = new WC_Product_Variation( $variation_id[0] );
        return '' . $term . '' . ' - (' . wp_kses( woocommerce_price( $_product->get_price() ), array() ) . ' )';
    }

    return $term;
}
```

And this is how it's in front: [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EHZCz.jpg)

Could anybody tell me how can I move everything starting from "-" to the next line?

It has to look this way:
38 Euro
20 0000

Comment: `str_replace('-', '<br>', $string)`?

Comment: Could you please write a whole line, i'am 0 at codding)

Comment: That is the whole line. I don't know where your current values are but that is the code to change a `-` to a new line (in HTML).

Answer (score 0):

You can change the return part to this:

```php
if ( $parent > 0 ) {
    $_product = new WC_Product_Variation( $variation_id[0] );
    return '' . $term . '' . ' <br/> ' . wp_kses( woocommerce_price( $_product->get_price(), array() ) . ' )';
}

return $term;
```

Also, edit your code in the part that returns the HTML to unescape the $name variable:

```php
return sprintf( '<li class="swatch swatch-label swatch-%s %s %s %s %s" title="%s" data-value="%s" data-tooltip_type="%s" data-tooltip_value="%s"><span class="swatch-inner swatch-label-inner">%s</span></li>', esc_attr( $slug ), esc_attr( $selected ), esc_attr( $style ), esc_attr( $flex_mode_class ), esc_attr( $tooltip_class ), $name, esc_attr( $slug ), esc_attr( $tooltip ), esc_attr( $tooltip_value ), $name );
```

In addition, to not break your grid, you will need to add this css to your stylesheet, or in the theme setting, in Custom CSS:

```css
.xt_woovs-single-product .xt_woovs-swatches .swatch.swatch-label {
    height: auto !important;
    text-align: left !important;
}
```

Comment: Didn't work, now this <br/> is shown in swatch [link](https://pavel-ms.store/product/air-jordan-test-kategorij/)

Comment: You need to check where you are displaying the output of the display_price_in_variation_option_name function in your template, that output is escaping the html characters, you must make it non-escaping in this case, in order to insert html characters into the string returned by your display_price_in_variation_option_name function

If you show me the template or where you show the return of the function display_price_in_variation_option_name I can tell you how to do it.

Comment: If you're using a Blade template, and displaying like 
{ display_price_in_variation_option_name } is just a case to add the marks to non-scaping: {!!  display_price_in_variation_option_name !!}

Comment: I have no idea what are you asking me. I work only with plugins/ I'am "0" at coding

Comment: Please dont publish access to your site here, please download your site and search in all the files where you have this string: swatch-label-inner and let me know teh code after this string

Comment: '<li class="swatch swatch-label swatch-%s %s %s %s %s" title="%s" data-value="%s" data-tooltip_type="%s" data-tooltip_value="%s"><span class="swatch-inner swatch-label-inner">%s</span></li>',

Comment: this is the only one that is found

Comment: 'return sprintf(
   '<li class="swatch swatch-label swatch-%s %s %s %s %s" title="%s" data-value="%s" data-tooltip_type="%s" data-tooltip_value="%s"><span class="swatch-inner swatch-label-inner">%s</span></li>',
   esc_attr( $slug ),
            esc_attr( $selected ),
            esc_attr( $style ),
            esc_attr( $flex_mode_class ),
            esc_attr( $tooltip_class ),
   esc_attr( $name ),
   esc_attr( $slug ),
            esc_attr( $tooltip ),
            esc_attr( $tooltip_value ),
   esc_html( $name )
  );
 }

Comment: Got it, please use the code AS I POST IN MY RESPONSE (is <br />, NOT </br>), and in this last code youposted change the last escaped attribute, as I posted in my reply.

Comment: Also I've added some custom css to my response that you will need to not break your grid

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your help my dear friend, but it didn't help((( Here the RETURN part: 'return  ''.$term.'' .' <br /> '. wp_kses( woocommerce_price( $_product->get_price() ), array() );'

Comment: return sprintf(
   '<li class="swatch swatch-label swatch-%s %s %s %s %s" title="%s" data-value="%s" data-tooltip_type="%s" data-tooltip_value="%s"><span class="swatch-inner swatch-label-inner">%s</span></li>',
   esc_attr( $slug ),
            esc_attr( $selected ),
            esc_attr( $style ),
            esc_attr( $flex_mode_class ),
            esc_attr( $tooltip_class ),
   $name,
   esc_attr( $slug ),
            esc_attr( $tooltip ),
            esc_attr( $tooltip_value ),
   $name
  );

Comment: And this the part of the second code

Comment: Also inserted the css, but i believe it doesn't break all this codes?

Comment: Maybe there is some php code, that activates html all over the website? Or inside special plugin?

Comment: OR maybe we could make 2 function: 1)to display name of the attr 2) to display price? On different lines via php and not html?

Comment: I think you need a consultory on that case, feel free to contact anyone or me at josepedrodiaz at gmail com anyona knowing wordpress and php can make a fix quickly

Comment: Thanks for your time my dear friend! I'll write to that address in a day or two